# Python Bizarre Error - Variable Referenced Before Assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

I keep on getting an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment`.

However, I'm absolutely positive that the variable is not referenced before assignment!

Here's my code:

```
def get_models(self,x=None,y=None):
        bioservices_up_obj = UniProt()
        bioservices_quickgo_obj = QuickGO()
        res = bioservices_quickgo_obj.Annotation_from_protein(protein=str(Brick.part_attrib(self,'uniprot_id')))
        go_id = []
        go_number = len(res['goID'])
        for i in range(go_number):
            go_id.append(str(res.iloc[i]['goID']))
        results = bioservices_up_obj.search(go_id[:go_number],format="tab",columns="id",sort="score",maxTrials=2)
        print results
```

All the other variables seem to print out fine, but for some reason I keep getting this error.

Comment: Can you post the full exception's traceback?

Comment: Are you sure the traceback points to this function? Whats the line number traceback shows?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/willem/Documents/Python_Work/assignment2_update3.py", line 172, in get_models
    results = bioservices_up_obj.search(go_id[:go_number],format="tab",columns="id",sort="score",maxTrials=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bioservices/uniprot.py", line 470, in search
    return res
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/willem/Documents/Python_Work/assignment2_update3.py", line 172, in get_models
    results = bioservices_up_obj.search(go_id[:go_number],format="tab",columns="id",sort="score",maxTrials=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bioservices/uniprot.py", line 470, in search
    return res
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment

Comment: Oh right I see, it's in the module that I imported, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the source of the library you're using

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bioservices/uniprot.py", line 470, in search
```

It appears that line 470 does actually have a bug. Line 459 in the same file is commented out in the latest version, which appears to be causing the bug.

Downloaded the tarball from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bioservices), opened `uniprot.py`, observed:

```
#res = s.request("/uniprot/?query=zap70+AND+organism:9606&format=xml", params)
trials = 3
while trials<maxTrials:
    try:
        res = self.request("uniprot/?query=%s" % query + "&" + params, "txt")
        trials = maxTrials + 1
    except:
        self.logging.warning("Trying again...")
        import time
        time.sleep(2)
        trials += 1
return res
```

Notice the commented first line (line 459 in the file). You could experiment with uncommenting that line, but I'm unfamiliar with the library so I don't know what that might do.

The project bug tracker is [here](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/bioservices/tickets), maybe you could submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had seen that, but I don't think that uncommenting that line is the solution. I think that it lies with the placement of the bottom line, `return res`. For some reason, I think it needs to be indented inline with the `except` line, but even that doesn't work!

Comment: If I were debugging it, I'd first try putting the `return res` at the end of the `try` block (ie just after `trials = maxTrials` and indented to the same level) - although it's impossible to know what problems that will cause without knowing the library and testing it a bit.

Comment: Yeah I did actually try that but it still didnt work - then I just got the output 'None' which shouldn't have been possible with the parameters that I entered. Luckily there is an alternative version of the same function in the package so I'm using that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Probably looking to traceback the function `bioservices_up_obj.search` is returning variable `res` which is undefined. So the problem is not in `get_models`.

I have looked into the code of `uniprot.py` at line [464](https://www.assembla.com/code/bioservices/subversion/nodes/322/trunk/bioservices/src/bioservices/uniprot.py#ln464) it do a while loop based on some limitied tries to get the response for a query url if all tries failed it will exit and hence the variable `res` remains undefined as the `res` is only defined in try block.

I Will suggest you to raise an exception at line 469 by manually changing the library code to check what exactly went wrong with query url

Comment: Yes I can see now that it's in a module that I imported. Now I just have to figure out how to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the whole traceback message.I thinck the exception comes from another method.

**Sorry :** I can't add comments.